# Itext 7.1 add paragraph to document

Tags: java, itext7

In iText 7.0 I added content to a pdf document using the code below and everything worked as expected.

```
ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
PdfWriter writer = new PdfWriter(out);
PdfDocument pdfDocument = new PdfDocument(writer);
try {
    LicenseKey.loadLicenseFile(".../key.xml");
    Document document = new Document(pdfDocument);
    document.add(new Paragraph("Some content"));
                //---more code----
```

When using version 7.1.0 I get an exception on the line

```
document.add(new Paragraph("Some content"));
```

Exception:

```
See nested exception;
nestedexceptionis:com.itextpdf.kernel.PdfException: document.has.no.pages
```

When I catch the Throwable that is thrown during the document.add call I get a

```
 NoSuchMethodError
com/itextpdf/layout/Document.add(Lcom/itextpdf/layout/element/IBlockElement;)Lcom/itextpdf/layout/Document;
```

Comment: Have you tried without loading the license file?

Comment: Yes, same issue

Comment: I asked because I cannot reproduce your issue. I have tested your code without license key loading, without `---more code----` but with closing bracket, and it works without issue. Thus, I assume, either your license loading or your "more code" causes an exception and the `document.has.no.pages` merely is a secondary effect of that original exception.

Comment: I use Itext 7.1.0
Licensekey 3.0.0
Java EE6 
Java 8
WAS 8.5 (full profile)

Comment: I get a NoSuchMethodError

com/itextpdf/layout/Document.add(Lcom/itextpdf/layout/element/IBlockElement;)Lcom/itextpdf/layout/Document;

Comment: Have you both compiled and run your code against the same iText version 7.1.0? Or are there multiple iText versions on the classpath? That `NoSuchMethodError` is weird because that method is both present in 7.0.x and 7.1.x...

Comment: Seems something goes wrong when Try to add something to the document. 

Haven't used pdfDocument.addNewPage(). but don't see that in any of the documentation either

Comment: Ah, I see, in 7.0.1 the method signature was `<T extends IElement> Document add(BlockElement<T> element)`, now it's `Document add(IBlockElement element)`. So you appear to have compiled your code with at least iText 7.0.2 but run it using at most iText 7.0.1. That won't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In comments it turns out that there actually is a

```
NoSuchMethodError com/itextpdf/layout/Document.add(Lcom/itextpdf/layout/element/IBlockElement;)Lcom/itextpdf/layout/Document;
```

causing this issue.

Since 7.0.2 the iText 7 layout `Document` class has a method

```
public Document add(IBlockElement element)
```

Up to 7.0.1 there was no Interface `IBlockElement`; the `add` method signature was different and used generics explicitly

```
public <T extends IElement> Document add(BlockElement<T> element)
```

This change was committed 2016-11-25 13:45:32 in the git commit 7cfc57b25c9faca96bc15e39163730002d9e4c9a.

Thus, you appear to have compiled your code with at least iText 7.0.2 but run it using at most iText 7.0.1.

Please make sure you run your code with an iText version not earlier than you compiled it with.

Comment: How can I check/achieve that

Comment: @Bgvv1983 How do you deploy your code to WebSphere? As a WAR? Then check which libraries you put into your WAR file. As an EAR? Presumably also check included libs but I have not yet dealt with EARs. And also check whether your WebSphere server forces some old iText 7 jar on you. If it does, reconfigure WebSphere to supply updated iText 7 jars to your code.

Comment: When I brows the itext7 war in my ear file (there also an itext5 war in it)
i see in my WEB-INF/lib kernel-7.1.0 jar just as in my maven dependencies

Comment: *"i see in my WEB-INF/lib kernel-7.1.0 jar"* - But `Document` is not in the kernel.jar. It is in the layout.jar.

Comment: Same story also 7.1.0

Comment: @Bgvv1983 Well, somehow there appears to be an old layout.jar forced upon your code. Maybe you should add WebSphere specific tags and ask for help among people who can help you sorting out class loading issues on WebSphere...

Comment: Setup a new environment  and the problem was solved. So there was some old stuff somewhere around. Thnx!

Comment: @Bgvv1983 Great! Setting up freshly appears to be always a good strategy... ;)

Answer (score 1):

Try to `addNewPage()` to your `PdfDocument`

Comment: Thats a non existing method

Comment: Sure, it is.http://itextsupport.com/apidocs/itext7/latest/com/itextpdf/kernel/pdf/PdfDocument.html

Comment: thats PDFdocument instead of Document means other changes as well. Migth a solution but doesn't explain the differences with version 7.0

Comment: Which version did you used - 7.0.?
Which version do you want to use - 7.1.?

Comment: See question. Used 7.0 now I need to use 7.1

Comment: Sure, but there are many release notes (7.0.1 until 7.0.6) - it would be easier to detect the problem...